# Permissions obtained Event Handling in Android API level >=23

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have implemented Requesting permissions at Runtime but I am not sure when I can call method that needs the permissions.

I can not call the method immediately because user needs time for press "Yes" button in permission dialog.

It will be very useful to handle onPermissionsObtained event but I can not find any similar to that.

How to deal with that?

See my code for example

```
private void startBuildInCameraActivity(View v) {

    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), 
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), 
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        requestPermissions();


        //TODO init onPermissionObtained event handler here instead "return"
        return;
    }

    startCamera();
}
```

The problem is User needs to call startBuildInCameraActivity twice if he has not permissions. Otherwise startCamera() will be never called.

Comment: You should call `startCamera()` in your `startBuildInCameraActivity()` method in case you have wanted permissions, or in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, when permission is granted, which happens asynchronously.  In case you missed it, there is a good [article](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) about runtime permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Drez 21.
The solution is to make class implemented **FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback** and then:

```
private void startBuildInCameraActivity(View v) {

    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        requestPermissions();
    } else {
        startCamera();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (grantResults.length != 1 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.permissions_needs))
                .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
    } else {
        startCamera();
    }
}
```

[This class](https://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/src/com.example.android.camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.html) has already implemented this behavior - use it for example.